Wave equation without initial condition
Consider the hyperbolic equation on a rectangular domain of the form $(0, L_x) \times (0, L_y)$:
$$
a^2 u_{xx} - b^2 u_{yy} = f(x, y),
$$
with Dirichlet boundary conditions on $u$.
By using the separation of variables method, we find that the exact solution $u$ is given by
$$
u(x, y) = \sum_{n, m \geq 1} \frac{f_{nm}}{\left(\frac{an\pi}{L_x}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{bm\pi}{L_y}\right)^2} \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L_x}\right) \sin\left(\frac{m\pi y}{L_y}\right),
$$
where $f_{nm}$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$. This solution exists if
$$
\left|\frac{an\pi}{L_x} - \frac{bm\pi}{L_y}\right| \geq C
$$
for all $n, m \geq 1$. However, it may not be possible to satisfy this condition, as any irrational number can be approximated by rational numbers (by Diophantine approximation).
Am I correct?
Are there any references to this type of equation?
I appreciate any help you can provide.
